# Ubuntu 18.04.4 qemu-commandline options fails

Tags: ubuntu, qemu, fedora-core

Trying to virt-install a Fedora-coreos VM I have a known working ignition file from a Fedora install so it is valid.

When I run the command:

`virt-install --connect qemu:///system -n fedora-core --memory 2048 --os-variant=fedora28 --import --graphics=none --disk size=10,backing_store=/data2/virtlib-images/fedora-coreos-31.20200323.3.2-qemu.x86_64.qcow2 --qemu-commandline="-fw_cfg name=opt/com.coreos/config,file=corebk.ign"`

the error is

```
Starting install...
Allocating 'fedora-core.qcow2'                                                       |  10 GB  00:00:00     
ERROR    internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2020-04-17T00:02:22.907508Z qemu-system-x86_64: -fw_cfg name=opt/com.coreos/config,file=corebk.ign: can't load corebk.ign
Removing disk 'fedora-core.qcow2'                                                    |    0 B  00:00:00     
Domain installation does not appear to have been successful.
```

It appears the -fw_cfg " flags are not working.
saw oldpost about qemu-kvm-ev being the missing package checked for pakage but not available in 18.04.4.
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The command line refers to a file "corebk.ign"; the error message says it can't load that file. Does the file exist? Did you typo the filename or forget to set it up? Do you have read permissions on it?

Comment: Peter The file is in directory I set it to be in Group KVM like other things in virtlib dir. The permissions and ownership are set the same as the working Fedora System Ubuntu just fails to build the VM

Answer (score 1):

The ignition file is not found.
I quote from [Fedora CoreOS - Getting Started](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora-coreos/getting-started/)

> When using virt-install, you must specify **absolute paths** to the image and the Ignition file.

Late answer, I know, but for future reference.